# how to choose the version of xcode for compilation C++ codes from command line with cmake scripts

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

In the MAC there are two xcode APP: one is xcode4 and the other is xcode5. When I compile the C++ project with cmake, it will invoke xcode 5 directly rather than  xcode 4, and I was wondering whether there is a way to call xcode 4 directly when I invoke cmake scripts from command line. Thanks.

EDIT:

Final solution is

```
sudo xcode-select --switch Path/to/xcode4
```

After that setting, it will work. I try to set the enviroment varialbe DEVELOPER_DIR, although I can clearly see that the directed path is xcode4, when invoking cmake scripts it still call xcode5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently used Xcode version can be received by executing:

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

You can change it by modifying environment variable `DEVELOPER_DIR`. From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html):

```
   DEVELOPER_DIR
      Overrides the active developer directory. When DEVELOPER_DIR is set,
      its  value  will  be  used instead of the system-wide
      active developer directory.
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work with cmake. When cmake scripts are invoked, xcode 5 is called rather than xcode4 even though after setting DEVELOPER_DIER, xcode path is directed to xcode4.